# Captura do valor do cookie de modo simplificado por javascript

Tags: javascript

Para concretização do meu trabalho preciso capturar de modo simplificado os valores presentes no PrimeiroCookie e no SegundoCookie. O valor de cada um desses cookies é um caminho da web variável (no PrimeroCaminho é para onde a janela principal aponta; no SegundoCaminho é para onde uma janela acessória, um `<iframe>`, aponta). A intenção é guardar informações de onde o usuário esteve e, quando ele retornar ao http://www.meusite.com ele será devolvido exatamente nas páginas onde parou, tanto principal quanto acessória.

Para criação do cookie estou usando:

```
<script language="javascript">
    document.cookie = 'PrimeiroCaminho=' + window.location + '; expires=Mon, 21 Nov 2078 12:00:00 UTC; path=/';
</script>
```

Para leitura do cookie essa foi minha primeira tentativa...

```
<script language="javascript">
    var re = new RegExp(PrimeiroCaminho + "=");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    return (value != null) ? decodeURI(value[1]) : null);
    var str = getCookie("PrimeiroCaminho");
    if (str.match(/html/)) {
        document.write ("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;' + getCookie('PrimeiroCaminho') + ' />");
        }
    else if {
        document.write ("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='4;http://www.meusite.com/' />");
        }
</script>
```

...e essa está sendo minha segunda, cuja qual acredito mais próxima do correto...

```
<script language="javascript">
    var user = getCookie("PrimeiroCaminho");
    var name = PrimeiroCaminho + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
            }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            document.write ("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;' + return c.substring(name.length, c.length) + ' />");
            }
        }
        else if {
            document.write ("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='4;http://www.meusite.com/' />");
            }
</script>
```

...mas ainda não consegui qualquer êxito. A intenção, relativamente à janela principal, é que o comando respeitasse essa dinâmica de que, se o PrimeiroCookie existir, redirecionasse (por meio de `<meta>` temporizada em 3s) o usuário para o valor guardado no PrimeiroCookie, mas, se esse PrimeiroCookie não existisse, redirecionasse (por meio de `<meta>` temporizada em 4s) o usuário para http://www.meusite.com/.

Relativamente à janela acessória o esquema seria o mesmo. Tudo de modo muito simples. Grato a quem puder ajudar esse pobre curioso em javascript.

---

Estive fuçando bastante no código e encontrei essa solução, que não era bem a que eu queria (não tem temporizador; o método me obriga a manter pastas e subpastas com o mesmo número de caracteres para que o `slice` funcione sempre no ponto certo; o método me obriga a esconder no `cookie` algum `código` para poder ser verificado) mas funcionou para o que eu queria:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var cookiecontent = document.cookie.slice(9, 81);
    var str = cookiecontent;
    if (str.match(/código/)) {
        location.href = PrimeiroCaminho;
        }
    else if (str.length == 0) {
        location.href = "http://www.meusite.com/";
        }
</script>
```

Se alguém, eventualmente, pensar numa solução, não deixe de postar!

Answer (score 0):

Adaptando o código da solução próxima ao que você quer, você pode utilizar o `split` para pegar a última ocorrência de `/` e o temporizador pode ser adicionado com `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var partes = document.cookie.split('/');
  var cookiecontent = partes(partes.length - 2);
  var str = cookiecontent;

  if (str === 'código')) {
    location.href = encodeURIComponent(PrimeiroCaminho);
  } else if (str.length == 0) {
    location.href = "http://www.meusite.com/";
  }
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Mas tanto na minha última solução alternativa, quanto na sua, o `location.href` no Internet Explorer, no Edge e no Chrome simplesmente não funciona. No Firefox e no Opera está funcionando corretamente. Algo entre eles funciona diferente?

Comment: Sobre o temporizador eu havia condicionado minha solução alternativa a uma função `VerifyCookie()` e no `body`, colocado algo assim: `onload="setTimeout(function(){VerifyCookie()},5000);`. Isso funcionou no Firefox e no Opera, mas como disse, evoluindo a rotina do script para `location.href`, no Internet Explorer, Edge e Chrome simplesmente não funciona. Muito estranho! A propósito, sua solução está muito mais elegante, então a adotei!

Comment: Talvez uma alternativa ao `location.href`, pelo que andei pesquisando, poderia ser a de fazer o `document.write` escrever `<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;url=PrimeiroCaminho' />`. Mas isso não funcionou em nenhum navegador.

Comment: @cpcolavite não esqueça de dar um upvote e aceitar a resposta se a mesma lhe atendeu

Comment: Um adendo sobre o `location.href`: funcionando no Firefox (desktop e mobile), no Opera (desktop e mobile), no Edge (mobile) e no Chrome (mobile); não funciona no Internet Explorer (desktop), no Edge (desktop) e nem no Chrome (desktop).